# How do I use map() in nextjs 14?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, react-router, frontend

I am trying to iterate over the response I get from an API using the `map()` method but I keep getting the error 'drinks.map is not a function'. Below is my code

Drinks

```
import DrinksList from "@/components/DrinksList";

const url = "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?f=a";

const fetchDrinks = async () => {
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  const response = await fetch(url);

  // throw error
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch");
  }

  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
};

const Drinks = async () => {
  const data = await fetchDrinks();

  return (
    <div>
      <DrinksList drinks={data} />
    </div>
  );
};
export default Drinks;
```

I have tried checking if I had any typos.

Answer (score 1):

The basic issue is that the fetched data is an object with a `drinks` property that is the array you would like to render.

```json
{
  "drinks": [
    {
      "idDrink": "17222",
      "strDrink": "A1",
      "strDrinkAlternate": null,
      ...
      "strImageAttribution": null,
      "strCreativeCommonsConfirmed": "No",
      "dateModified": "2017-09-07 21:42:09"
    },
    {
      "idDrink": "13501",
      "strDrink": "ABC",
      "strDrinkAlternate": null,
      ...
      "strImageAttribution": null,
      "strCreativeCommonsConfirmed": "No",
      "dateModified": "2016-08-31 19:32:08"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

The code is passing this object as the `drinks` prop and trying to call a `map` method that is undefined, e.g. the error message that "map is not a function". Pass the `response.drinks` array to the child component.

```js
const url = "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?f=a";

const fetchDrinks = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(url);

  // throw error
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch");
  }

  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
};
```

```
const Drinks = async () => {
  const { drinks } = await fetchDrinks(); // <-- destructure drinks

  return (
    <div>
      <DrinksList drinks={drinks} /> // <-- pass drinks state array
    </div>
  );
};

export default Drinks;
```

It's a good idea to also provide a default value for the `drinks` prop in case you render a `DrinksList` component and pass an undefined `drinks` prop.

```
const DrinksList = ({ drinks = [] }) => {
  ...

  return (
    ...
    {drinks.map(drink => (
      <div key={drink.idDrink}>
        ...
      </div>
    ))}
    ...
  );
};
```

Comment: I had the same first thought about async components, but then looked at the docs and apparently Next.js has support for this server side. Here's what I found quickly https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating

Comment: @BrianThompson Thanks for the info. Seems a bit odd, but then again, I'm not a Next.js guy either so OFC it seems weird to have `async` components. But if that's how it works there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to iterate `drinks` like this. Since `drinks` is an Array whose first element is an object called `drinks` which again is an Array of Objects.

So I guess you can use `map()` function like this on `drinks`.

```
drinks[0]?.drinks.map((item, index) => {
        return <div key={index}>{item.strIngredient2}</div>;
      })
```

Comment: thank you, Santra
It still doesn't work